# Mysql WHERE using AND & CASE Condition

Tags: mysql, case, where-clause

I want to add where when the given platform variable in my procedure is not null.

-- Edit --

Okay, this is a procedure. Program filters results based on user's selection. (platform selection)

So the platform variable is declared on the procedure. If a user sends any platform ids to procedure, then the result must filtered with platform variable. But if platform variable is null or undefined, then get all results.

Note: I want to find a way to include multiple platform ID's inside a CASE statement

You can find the complete code below.

-- / Edit --

```
(
SELECT gn.title, gn.slug, gn.created_at, gn.content, gi.image, 'news' as `type` FROM `game_news` gn 
CROSS JOIN `gallery_images` gi ON gi.foreign_key = gn.id
CROSS JOIN `game_platforms` gp
LEFT JOIN `game_news_platform_relation` gnpr ON gnpr.news_id = gn.`id` 
WHERE gi.gallery_id = 7 AND gi.is_main = '1' AND `gi`.`thumbnail_id` = 16 AND gn.deleted_at IS NULL AND gi.deleted_at IS NULL
AND (
    CASE 
        WHEN platform is NOT NULL 
            THEN gnpr.platform_id IN(platform)
    END
    )
GROUP BY gn.id
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT gr.title, gr.slug, gr.created_at, gr.content, gi.image, 'review' as `type` FROM `game_reviews` gr 
CROSS JOIN `gallery_images` gi ON gi.foreign_key = gr.id
CROSS JOIN `game_platforms` gp
LEFT JOIN `game_review_platform_relation` grpr ON grpr.review_id = gr.`id` 
WHERE gi.gallery_id = 6 AND gi.is_main = '1' AND `gi`.`thumbnail_id` = 14 AND gr.deleted_at IS NULL AND gi.deleted_at IS NULL
AND (
    CASE 
        WHEN platform is NOT NULL 
            THEN grpr.platform_id IN(platform) 
    END
    )
GROUP BY gr.id
)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT post_offset, post_limit
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What is the IN(platform) for? why not just `CASE WHEN platform is not null and platform = 'whatever' THEN gnpr.platform_id END`?

Comment: @GolezTrol I agree about the confusion, but the syntax error is because the OP has said he doesn't know how to do this and is giving pseudo code to show what he wants.

Comment: I can't see the original query

Comment: I will not argue am i deleted or not. I made a mistake, so i deleted it and after a second i re-enabled it. So what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use IN() inside of a case it has to be in the WHEN portion so you can do it like this.

```
AND
(   CASE
      WHEN platform IS NOT NULL AND gnpr.platform_id IN(platform)
      THEN gnpr.platform_id
      ELSE 1
    END
)
```

you could also add another WHEN to pull in everything like this.

```
AND
(   CASE
      WHEN platform IS NOT NULL AND gnpr.platform_id IN(platform)
      THEN gnpr.platform_id
      WHEN platform IS NULL
      THEN gnpr.platform_id
    END
)
```

Comment: There is no id relation between these tables (news and galleries). So i have to do that with Cross join.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan see my edit for how to put the IN() inside a CASE

Comment: Yeah i saw that bro. Instead of being negative, you are the only person here thinks professionally and really helpful. Thank you. And one more thing; query always returns 0 with your code. But this is the only answer that could be useful.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan well it depends on what data you have and what you are querying off of. if you want more help on this I will need to have some way to run the query myself.. if you could set up a SQLFIDDLE for us to work with you can get an answer much faster :)

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan sure thing! you can probably clean up this query too.. i'd have to play around with it but I think you can combine it into one query and use COALESCE() for null values.. i'll throw something together it may give you a good idea :)

Comment: Oh... It is failing when i don't define the platform variable... Thank you anyway. Any idea?

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan try it with an else and are you using platform anywhere else?

Comment: No i'm not. I will try with else but should i use like 1 = 1 in else?

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan no.. the only place where you use boolean statements is in the WHEN the THEN and ELSE are just putting stuff in there whether thats a string or number of whatever you want in there :)

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan try my second case statement I think that will do better.

Comment: 1 is working :) 1 is the best number :) 0 = false, 1 = true. So it's working now. Thank you so much again and again!

Answer (score 0):

Why instead of using case on the where clause, use a LEFT JOIN from you table to platform. Then on the where clause evaluate if platform.ID is NOT null. Hope the idea helps you.

**EDIT**

If you want to use a CASE in the WHERE clause you need to tranform it to boolean. Something like this:

```
SELECT p FROM Table WHERE (CASE WHEN Machine ='myMachine' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Comment: They didn't at first. And left join does solve the issue. No case needed when you use a left join.

Comment: @GolezTrol ? the query has had the left join to the gnpr table from when the question was asked. not sure if platform is in a different table since it doesn't have a table alias before it.

Comment: @JohnRuddell It didn't, and it also had a syntax error in the case statement, but some changes are not logged when they happen quickly. Doesn't really matter, although it makes this answer look silly, althought it answered the original question and I think it is still the right answer.

Comment: I would use left join if i could. My main question is not about using joins. My question is, how can i use a case or if / else in the where condition.

Comment: @GolezTrol ah gotcha, I had looked at the edit history and didn't see that but I gotcha, nice catch.

Comment: ericpap, CASE statements don't require a boolean response, you can put whatever you want in the THEN, ELSE parts of the CASE, the only boolean expression is in the WHEN part. and that boolean part can be what the OP had aka `WHEN platform IS NOT NULL`